# ApacheJMeter dynamic load testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I've build an application which reacts on resource demand (i.e., number of http accesses). To test it, I want to generate http GET requests programmatically with ApacheJMeter. Unfortunately I cannot find any possibility to generate different numbers of http GET's during predefined segments of the test case.
A test should look like that for example:

```
seconds 0 to 30: 1000 GET requests per second
seconds 31 to 60: 5000 GET request per second
seconds 61 to 90: 15000 GET request per second
seconds 91 to 120: 5000 GET request per second
seconds 121 to 150: 1000 GET request per second
```

I hope this is possible, thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=ThroughputShapingTimer) Plugin for that.
I used this [Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughput Shaping Timer plugin allows for setting up multiple segments of traffic at different rates

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/